# select with ng-repeat does not work

Tags: angularjs

having some strange issue with select & ng-repeat.. the value gets bound if i specify it from controller, but not if i get it from api call...

```
<div>Operator is: {{condition.operator}}</div>
<select ng-model="condition.operator">
   <option ng-repeat="operator in operators" value="{{operator.value}}">{{operator.displayName}}</option>
</select>
```

why this strange behavior?? i tried it with ng-options that solved the problem, so do we have to use ng-options always with select and not ng-repeat??

Comment: check my answer too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ng-options

```
<select ng-model="filterCondition.operator" ng-options="operator.value as operator.displayName for operator in operators">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do either the both ways

**First Method** - **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmjQ/16/)**

```
  <select ng-model="condition.operator">
     <option ng-repeat="operator in operators" value="{{operator.value}}">
         {{operator.displayName}}  
      </option>
  </select>
```

**Second Method** - **[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmjQ/17/)**

```
<select ng-model="condition.operator" ng-options="operator.value as operator.displayName for operator in operators"/>
```